# GraphQL mutation with Input type doesn't pass argument to resolver

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I am trying to execute a mutation taking an input type object as parameter but the parameter is not passed to the resolver

Below are my typeDefs.ts and resolver.ts files:

typeDefs.ts

```js
type Mutation {
  registerUser(input: UserRegistrationInput): AuthPayload
}

input UserRegistrationInput {
  email: String
  password: String
}

type AuthPayload {
  token: String
  message: String
}
```

resolver.ts

```js
Mutation: {
  registerUser: (_, args) => {
    console.log(args)
  }
}
```

When I execute this mutation in the GraphQL playground with the query variables, console.log() echo an empty object `{}`

**Mutation**

```js
// Mutation
mutation RegisterUser($input: UserRegistrationInput) {
  registerUser(input: $input) {
    message
    token
  }
}

// Query variables
{
  "input": {
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "password": "123456"
  }
}
```

However if the mutation takes different parameters instead of an input type, it works. console.log() echo the object `{ "email": "john.doe@example.com", "password": "123456" }`

typeDefs.ts

```js
type Mutation {
  registerUser(email: String, password: String): AuthPayload
}
```

**Mutation**

```js
// Mutation
mutation RegisterUser($email: String, $password: String) {
  registerUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
    message
    token
  }
}

// Query variables
{
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "password": "123456"
}
```

I can't figure out why in case of input type the arguments are not passed to the resolver.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Try with `input: UserRegistrationInput!` (non-null) and see whether you get validation errors.

Comment: I get the following error message: `Variable "$input" of required type "UserRegistrationInput!" was not provided.`

Comment: Looks like either you're not sending the query variables you think, or there's a typo (invisible characters?) somewhere. Check the outgoing http request.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue, non input type args is getting passed properly. One more thing I noticed is that in the playground if I pass the same input args, it reflects in the resolver, but not when I'm passing the same using queryVariables from my FE app.